# Entity Framework Database First: How do I customize the translation process to avoid non-descriptive relationship property names?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I generated the edmx for my database, and that worked great -- however the problem now is that on a few of my models with multiple relationships to the same table/model have dumb names.

Such as:

```
Book:
  User
  User1
  User2
```

Those relationships aren't very descriptive. Here are the column names:

- UserId_Owner
- UserId_CreatedBy
- UserId_UpdatedBy

The database I'm working with has all the foreign keys written this way:
`{Table}Id_{RelationshipName}`

So, using that pattern, I'd like to change the edmx generation to pull out the `RelationshipName`.
Is there a way to configure that?

Comment: I'm not immediately putting this as an answer because it may be out of scope for your question, though it may be the best way to achieve what you want. Have you taken a look at Code First against an existing database?

Comment: I have considered it yeah, unfortunately, there are 428 tables / models, so I'd like as much to be as automatic as possible.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Still I'd reconsider code first though, designer from database is no longer supported from EF7 on. Not to mention, with a project that big if you'll ever need to customize something you'll quickly run into troubles with designer from database. In my opionion designer is a good tool for quickly setting up a database for a small project, but you should reconsider using it for a project that big.

Comment: EF7 has a scaffold generator, which generates a code-first-like setup -- I actually started with EF7, but switched to EF6 because EF7 doesn't have lazy loading.  The database I'm working with has consistent naming convention, So I'd like to take advantage of that. (esp since every model has *at least* 3 relationships)